# How to check if functions are linear?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that a function is linear if $f(ax+by) = af(x)+bf(y)$, but whilst doing some exercises I came across to this one where it says that I have to check if the following functions are linear. I don't really understand how should I proceed.

\begin{align*}
  f: \mathbb{K}^{3} &\to \operatorname{Mat}(2,1 ; \mathbb{K})\\
  (x, y, z) &\mapsto \begin{bmatrix}x-y\\ y-z\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  g: \mathbb{K}[x] &\to \mathbb{K}[x]\\
  P(x) &\mapsto P'(x)+2P''(x)+1
\end{align*}

Comment: You proceed by checking that the definition is satisfied. Evaluate $f$ at the sum of two inputs and check that the answer is the same as summing the two outputs. (Do the same for multiplication by a scalar;)

Comment: hint for $g$: compute $g(0)$, where as argument I mean the polynomial which is identically $0$ on $\mathbb{K}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditions of linearity of function is $(1)f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(cx)=cf(x)$ where $c$ is scalar. Alternatively we may write $f(cx+dy)=cf(x)+df(x)$, $c$, $d$ are scalars. If a function satisfy these properties we declared it as linear. As $f(x) = tx$  is linear.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).